# Error in sending response from python to Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

When control comes out of a text field, I am calling a script which in turn calls a python function to return a response. when calling the function I am getting an error::POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/getcustomernamefromexcel 403 (Forbidden)

Html file including script :

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
<html>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <script type ="text/javascript">
      function getCustomerName() {
        var x = document.ipwhitelistindex.AWSID.value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.ipwhitelistindex.getElementById("CUSTNAME").innerHTML  = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('POST', 'getcustomernamefromexcel', true);
    xhttp.send(x);
       }
    </script>
    <h1>IP Whitelisting</h1>
    <form name = "ipwhitelistindex" action = 'ipwhitelisting' method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <center>
            <table>
        <tr><td>Enter AWS Account Id </td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = AWSID onblur="getCustomerName()"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer Name </td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = CUSTNAME style = "background-color : lightgrey" readonly></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Enter list of IPS seperated with(,) </td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = IPS></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Enter description </td><td>:</td><td><input type = 'text' name = DESC></td></tr>
            </table><br>
            <input type = 'submit' value = 'submit'>
        </center>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

python code :

```
 def getcustomernamefromexcel(request):
    return HttpResponse('html')
```

Comment: Try a `JsonReponse` instead of `HttpResponse`. For example, try this: `return JsonResponse({ 'msg': 'html' })`. Import `JsonResponse` from `django.http`.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 means the server refuses your query because you don't have the authorization. Are you not supposed to send any authorization in header, cookie or something else?

Check the authentification part of sever code

Another bug is in your server code, as you sent no authorization, it is supposed to response with 401.